# Python Cgi Programming Permissions

Tags: python, apache, cgi, cgi-bin

I am using a python cgi-script  and using it for few webpages on my server, Everything works fine when permission is manually set to 755.

But When i edit with some software for eg coda . It uploads with different permissions so, I have to manually again change the permission . I am sick of doing that every time my

.htaccess file has this thing in it

```
Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script .py
```

If you have any other alternate or solution to this problem so that i can set like chmod 755 for every .py script or something like that. DO tell.Like any shell script which i can run one time and then do the same. I am using ubuntu 12 server

I tried this, but,

```
#!/bin/bash
file=`find *.py`
chmod 775 $file
```

it can be used in bulk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the permissions set upon upload are [configurable](http://www.raisedeyebrow.com/blog/2009/06/strange-permissions-coda-file-uploads) in coda.

Alternatively, you could use `inotifywait` on the server (from [inotify-tools](https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki)) to add the executable bit whenever the scripts are modified:

```bsh
$ inotifywait -c -m -e modify -e create -e attrib  path/to/cgi-bin/ \ 
| while read pth; do
    chmod +x "$(echo $pth | awk -F, '{print $1$3}')"
done
```

Or just `while /bin/true; do sleep 5 && chmod 755 path/to/cgi-bin/*.py; done` - it shouldn't matter that much.

If you are feeling adventurous, you could also use Python's built-in http server module and a `CGIHTTPRequestHandler` with an overloaded [`is_executable()`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/cbdd6852a274/Lib/http/server.py#l977) method.

Still, I'm curious to see if this can be handled entirely from the apache config. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks @gvalkov , It worked and helped me. Great Answer by the way 
and i am really feeling very adventurous . 
so will try is_executable() method too.  :)